# What counter should be used for baked pastries? 焼菓子は何で数えますか?

Tags: counters, food

Baked pastries 焼菓子【やきがし】 encompass a wide array of items. What are some ways to count some of them? As one might in a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This calls for the 数え方の辞典

> **やきがし** 【焼き菓子】
>
> **枚【まい】、個、本、台**
> クッキーやビスケットなど切り分けずに食べる平面的な焼き菓子は「枚」、マドレーヌやカップケーキは「個」で数えます。パウンドケーキは「本」、焼き型で丸く焼き上げたスポンジケーキは「個」「台」で数えます。
>
> **切れ、ピース**
> 切り分けた焼き菓子は「切れ」「ピース」、それを小売りする場合は「個」などで数えます。

A rough translation is

> #### *yakigashi*
>
> ***mai***, ***ko***, ***hon***, ***dai***
> Flat *yakigashi* eaten without cutting like cookies, biscuits, etc. are counted with *mai*, madeleines, cupcakes, etc. with *ko*. Pound cakes are counted with *hon*, sponge cakes that are baked in a round pan with *ko* or *dai*.
>
> ***kire***, ***pīsu***
> Cut *yakigashi* are counted with *kire* or *pīsu* and when sold with *ko*.